# Geo Fence: Find number of features (points/lines/polygons) inside a polygon using oracle spatial

Tags: geolocation, oracle-spatial

How do i write a SQL query (using Oracle Spatial) to find the number of features available inside a polygon (geofence);

The features could be either points, lines or a polygon itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that statement:

```
select count(*) from geometry_table t where SDO_RELATE(t.geom_column, geofence, 'mask=INSIDE') = 'TRUE'
/
```

It is mandetory that the first parameter of `SDO_RELATE` is the geometry column with a spatial index.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the response. I was off the work for quite a while and couldn't respond to your answer. This executes perfectly.

Comment: You can use the simpler syntax: SDO_INSIDE(t.geom_column, geofence) = 'TRUE'. It has exactly the same effect, but is just simpler to write.

Answer (score -1):

***Update: Disregard this suggestion completely, Albert Godfrind said it is repeating what is already being done internally. So it is inefficient and slow:***

To add to Tims answer, it is good practice to combine SDO_FILTER and SDO_RELATE for performance reasons. SDO_FILTER is fast but returns too many geometries, it will give you all geometries whose minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) intersects with your fence's geometry. SDO_RELATE is exact but slow.
So combine both:

```
select count(*) 
from geometry_table t 
where SDO_FILTER(t.geom_column, geofence) = 'TRUE' and SDO_RELATE(t.geom_column, geofence, 'mask=INSIDE') = 'TRUE'
```

Regards, Chris

Comment: Sorry, but this is *totally wrong*. Doing what you suggest will just make the query run slower. The SDO_RELATE operator automatically applies the "primary filter" (i.e. the equivalent of the SDO_FILTER operator).

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that yet, has it always been like this? In that case, I apologize and I'll edit my comment so nobody uses my inefficient query.